# Use Google Apps Script to Assign a File to Multiple Folders - Like Shift+Z Feature

Tags: google-apps-script

In the Google Drive interface, a file can be assigned multiple folders by using the Shift+Z feature.  I am working a Google Apps Script project that will create a folder for each user in a spreadsheet.  It will also make copies of selected documents into the newly created folders.

What I am trying to find out though, is I have a specific document that I would like to add to those new folders, but I do not want to simply make copies.  I also do not want to simply move the file. The Shift+Z feature allows me to have the document in multiple places at once, changes to that document are reflected regardless of the folder.  Can this be done with script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Drive, a file can have more than one parent folder.  The addFile() method of the Folder class will add the file to the folder you are calling the method on.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File)

Comment: Anton, thanks so much for your help.  I must have just missed that method.  I will give it a try.  Thanks so much for your help!!